# Binding direction from Target to Source

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

Is it possible to have the binding go from Target to Source the first time and then operate in the TwoWay mode?

In other words, if my control (or Window, as in my case) has a `DependencyProperty` and it is set before the control is placed in the visual tree, can I make the bound ViewModel's Property first acquire the value?

When I'm trying it, the `DependencyProperty` seems to be set twice: the first time, to the value set by the target, and then - by the value set by the source, which is null.

Comment: Don't think it's possible, at least not without a lot of hackery, but would love to know *why* you need this.

Comment: @Kent Boogaart, that's disappointing. I'm trying to build a DialogWindow subclass of Window, that can accept a complex object as input. So, if I do `DialogWindow w = new DialogWindow(){ Data = SomeObj };` it would be made available to the ViewModel of this DialogWindow via typical binding

Comment: @NewDev your scenario sounds pretty standard -- it shouldn't require some crazy mutating binding.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have a situation where I want the target of the binding to act as the source of the first value.